# Arithmetics in IF statement (Batch)

Tags: batch-file, math, if-statement

I am currently learning how to program in batch, but I have encountered a problem. I tried to run this script but somehow it isn't working:

```
set /a x=5
if %x%+1 equ 6 (@echo x + 1 is equal to 6)
echo [%x%+1]
echo.
pause
```

This is what it prints:

```
[5+1]

Press a key to continue...
```

Basically I just want to know how to do arithmetics in an if statement.

Comment: You can not do that in Batch. The _only_ command that perform arithmetic operations is `set /A`, so you must do the operation _first_ (and store the result in a variable), and _then_ use such variable in any other command, like `if`...

Answer (score 3):

The `==` comparison operator always results in a string comparison. [`IF` command](http://ss64.com/nt/if.html) will only parse *numbers* when one of `EQU`, `NEQ`, `LSS`, `LEQ`, `GTR`, `GEQ` comparison operator is used. A non-numeric character in any of compared values leads to a string comparison as well.

Arithmetic expressions are allowed in [SET /a](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) commands only. You could use

```
set /a "x=5"
set /a "y=x+1"
if %y% equ 6 (@echo x + 1 is equal to 6)
echo [%x%+1]=%y%
echo.
pause
```

Comment: I know i can add that line but in Lua programming language i would have been able to write `if x+1 == 6 then...` and my question is can I do this in batch and if so, how?